# Run vim command when preview window is open

Tags: vim, neovim, viml

In neovim, when my completion plugin is triggered, it will print out the methods signature in a preview window

[image]

The preview window though, contains line numbers which is something I want to disable. So far, I though this would work

```
function! Preview_func()
  if &pvw
    setlocal nonum
   endif
endfunction

autocmd * BufCreate call Preview_func()
```

But no dice. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In autocommand definition *file pattern* ( here: * ) should come **after** *event* ( BufCreate ); also base on which autocompletion plugin you are using there may be an entrance to preview window or not so also check with *WinEnter* event:

```
autocmd WinEnter * call Preview_func()
```